# Get the index of the array when array object matching condition

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an array like this:

```
parent = [
    {'id':'id_1','level':'1-1','children':['id':'id_1','level':'1-1-0','children':[........]},
    {'id':'id_2','level':'2-2','children':['id':'id_1','level':'2-1-0','children':[........]}
]
```

How can I get the parent array index that match the condition of child array object

**For example:**

```
If (level == '2-1-0')
```

Output: 1

**Expected Behaviour:**

It should return 1 because level 2-1-0 present in 1'st index of parent array

**Note:**
I tried like below

```
var index = parent .findIndex(data => data.level== result.level);
```

It will not check child array object

Comment: The array stored in the `parent` variable is syntactically invalid: can you update your question? Also, is there arbitrary level of nesting for `children`?

Comment: You're right, this will not check the children in the object. You will have to go through each child array and check it against your `result.level`.

Comment: Your `children` array is not a va;id array. Also is its just to find the matching level from the child objects in the array? Asking this specifically because you children array already have an another children node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need recursion

```
const findItemNested = (arr, level, nestingKey) => (
  arr.reduce((a, item, index) => {
    if (a) return a;
    if (item.level === level) return index;
    if (item[nestingKey]) return findItemNested(item[nestingKey], level, nestingKey)
  }, null)
);
const testArr = [
      {
        'id':'id_1',
       'level':'1-1',
       'children':[
         {'id':'id_1'},
         {'level':'1-1-0'},
         {'children':[]}
       ]
      },
      {'id':'id_2','level':'2-2','children':[{'id':'id_1'},{'level':'2-1-0'},{'children':[]}]}
  ];

const res = findItemNested(testArr, '2-1-0', "children");

console.log(res) //  1
```

Comment: It's working 75% of my requirment, I made some update in this code .

Answer (score 3):

Your provided array is wrong, but I think that you need something like this:

```
const parent = [
    {'id':'id_1','level':'1-1','children':[{'id':'id_1','level':'1-1-0'}]},
    {'id':'id_2','level':'2-2','children':[{'id':'id_1','level':'2-1-0'}]}
]

const index = parent.findIndex(p => p.children.find(c => c.level === '2-1-0') !== undefined);

console.log(index);
```

In the place of '2-1-0' you should put the index, that you want to check.

Comment: This solution doesn't work for different depths (eg, level = '1-3-4-5')

Comment: Ok, the question not say about depths, but if encapsulate the logic into a function, we can use a recursive call to do this.

Answer (score 1):

It's a recursive problem, which can blow the stack for big arrays.

The script traverses the tree depth first and can be optimized to detect the requested level depth and only check that level, increasing the performance.

```js
var weirdProblem = level => (carry, current, idx) => {
  // bail if already found 
  if (carry > -1) {
    return carry;
  }

  // check current item's children and return current idx if matching
  if (current.children.some(child => child.level === level)) {
    return idx;
  }

  // traverse current item's children
  return current.children.reduce(weirdProblem(level), -1);
};

var index = parent.reduce(weirdProblem('2-1-0'), -1);
```

did not test the script.

Answer (score 0):

Your parent array is malformed, I guess it should be a nested structure.

Since children may also contains more children, you will need recursion for a deep search.

```js
const parent = [
    {"id": "id_1", "level": "1-1", "children": [{"id": "id_1", "level": "1-1-0", "children": []}]},
    {"id": "id_2", "level": "2-2", "children": [{"id": "id_1", "level": "2-1-0", "children": []}]}
];

function levelIndex(children, level) {
    return children.findIndex(child => child.level == level || levelIndex(child.children, level) >= 0);
}
    
const index = levelIndex(parent, "2-1-0");
console.log("Found index:", index)
```

Answer (score 0):

in .TS file:-

```
const parent = [
    {'id':'id_1',
     'level':'1-1',
     'children':[{'id':'id_1',
                  'level':'1-1-0'}]},
                 {'id':'id_2',
                  'level':'2-2',
                  'children':[{'id':'id_1',
                               'level':'2-1-0'}]}
]

const index = parent.filter(x => x.children.find(x => x.level === '2-1-0') !== undefined);

console.log(index);
```

Give this a try. I think it will work.